DataPower XSLTs: Append RFH Header as String to Well formatted XML

We've RFH header value as a string in **RFHHeader** variable. and we've Request payload xml wrapped in Envelope to be sent via MQs to Service Hub. But Service Hub is expecting the payload as showcased in **OUTPUT** 
(1) Can we just place/append RFHHeader string on top of a well formatted xml? 
(2) If not, Is there alternative way like StringBuilder in .Net C# to convert XML to String and then append to RFHHeader string? 
(3) Can you please help us with a solution or alternative approaches to handle this scenario? Thank You
INPUT 
  <xsl:variable name="RFHHeader" select="'RFH   d   3   <<mcd><Msd>XML</Msd></mcd>'"/>

  <Envelope EnvelopeID="EMI Rev 1.0">
     <MessageProtocol>MQ</MessageProtocol>
     <Message MessageID="GetAccountInfo">
        <Body BodyID="1" BodyType="Component">
            <AccountID>123456789</AccountID>
        </Body>
     </Message>
  </Envelope>

OUTPUT
   RFH   d   3   <<mcd><Msd>XML</Msd></mcd><Envelope EnvelopeID="EMI Rev 1.0><MessageProtocol>MQ</MessageProtocol><Message MessageID="GetAccountInfo"><Body BodyID="1" BodyType="Component"><AccountID>123456789</AccountID></Body></Message></Envelope>


RFH is a binary format, I doubt that the receiver wants it with spaces. Prepending the RFH normally is not enough, the message format in MQ should also reflect the presence of RFH.

Hello @StefanHegny, Yup we will populate ASCII Unicode characters in the actual RFH header. But do we have a solution or alternative approaches to handle this scenario?
